# Hosting a WCF in Windows Services

Tags: vb.net, wcf, service

I have a working WCF, it is written in VB. I need to host it in Windows Services on a remote server. I cannot use IIS (they uninstalled after I had it installed). Specs are to host in Windows Services, the only way I can get around that is to quit.

Many people have referred me to this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069.aspx -- but the link is not accurate for someone who has developed a WCF in VB. Even step 2 states to "Change Program.cs to Service.cs", working with VB Visual Studio does not issue .cs files. The documentation at Microsoft does not accommodate for VB development (although they list some VB code in the article, it's still not accurate).

What I need is an accurate how-to or step-by-step that will show me how to take my VB WCF and host it in Windows Services.

Any pointers, direction or general direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Found a MUCH better resource and answered my own question! Link: http://joefreeman.co.uk/blog/2010/03/creating-a-setup-project-for-a-windows-wcf-service-with-visual-studio/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a MUCH better resource and answered my own question! Link: http://joefreeman.co.uk/blog/2010/03/creating-a-setup-project-for-a-windows-wcf-service-with-visual-studio/